# Are you supposed to look at the source when javadoc is not clear?

Tags: java, android, open-source, javadoc

How am I, as a developer, supposed to find out what exactly some library code is supposed to do according to the API?

To be more specific, I'm trying to learn the Android API. It seems to me that the javadocs are not always clear, but when you start reading the SDK source code of classes like Activity, Fragment, View, you get a much better impression of what is actually going on.

But doesn't that invalidate the idea of having an API (= interface), where the actual implementation (source code) can change while the API remains the same? And if you look at the source code, aren't you more likely to take some behavior for granted which wasn't intended to be part of the API?

I'm also relatively new to the concept of Inversion Of Control, where you, for example, have to subclass and override lots of methods like onCreate or onDraw. It seems to me that necessarily there are lots of hidden things going on in the background without having to write any code about it, because the SDK code contains the actual main thread loop. For example, the app creates a window, displays an action bar, it paints a white background, reacts to certain events from the very beginning. But I didn't write any code for this behavior. I just left out code. It's all taken over by the SDK.

I have the impression that this paradigm makes the learning curve steeper because you would actually have to look up somewhere what happens when you write nothing or when you leave out specific lines of code. But in the docs I can only look up what happens after some method gets called (probably by me, probably by the SDK) but not when it's called and what happens if I don't call it or don't override it. So is there some recommended way to look up those things that are supposed to happen implicitly all the time?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com is more suitable for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For learning the Android SDK, I would start with their [developer website](http://developer.android.com/index.html). There are tons of tutorials, sample code, and explanations of the SDK to browse through.